# how i can find the number of occurrence of word in an sentence in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

i wrote an java script program that must do the following things : it must take the sentence from the text in the form and then find the number of occurrence of each word in the sentence alphabetically in table as following:

```
this : 5 times 
the : 2 times .....and so on
```

but in reality my program do the following and doesn't show the result when search button clicked and if we take the function  button-pressed() lonely  it works as the following:

```
this :1
this :2
this:3
this:4
this:5
the:1
the:2....and so on
```

i want to appear the last values without the redundant values ,so any help please this is my code :

```
<script type = "text/javascript"><!--
function buttonPressed() {
    var searchForm = document.getElementById( "searchForm" );
    var inputVal = document.getElementById( "inputVal" );
    var arr =inputVal.split(" ");
    var counts = {};
    arr.sort();
    for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
        var num = arr[i];
        if(counts[num])
            counts[num]=counts[num]+1 ;
        else
            counts[num]=1;

        document.writeln("<table border = \"4\">" );
        document.writeln( "<caption><h3>Search's Results: <h3/></caption>" );
        document.writeln( "<tr><td>"+arr[i]+" :</td><td>" +counts[num] + "</td></tr></tbody></table>" );
    }
} // end function buttonPressed
// --></script>

<form id = "searchForm" action = "">
<h1>The string to search is:<br /></h1>
<p>Enter Sentence  You Wnt To Find The Occurrence Of Each Word In It :
<input id = "inputVal" type = "text" />
<input name = "search" type = "button" value = "Search" onclick = "buttonPressed()" /><br /></p></form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this:

```
"mijn naam is niels, niels is mijn naam".split("niels").length - 1
// Will return 2
```

Which will split on the word, and you will have the number of matches

Comment: Soz, didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

the main problem that you're trying to output during calculation, your `document.writeln` statements are inside for loop

you need to move them out:

```
for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    var num = arr[i];
    counts[num] = (counts[num] ? counts[num] : 0) + 1 ;
}

document.writeln("<table border=\"4\">");
document.writeln("<caption><h3>Search's Results: <h3/></caption>");
for (var i in counts) {
    document.writeln("<tr><td>"+i+" :</td><td>"+counts[i]+"</td></tr>");
}
document.writeln("</tbody></table>");
```

NOTE: please read about [htmlencode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery) and [document.writeln](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_writeln.asp) functions, you're doing wrong output, as you're writing to the end of document, for your particular task is ok, but usually you need to do output into particular place on page, for this you will need to assign [innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) of some div

Comment: Damnit, you beat me to it XD Have a +1

Comment: thanks a lot but when i do the function lonely it work perfectly but when i use the form to get the sentence and click on the button there is no thing happened ,please do you have an idea ?

Comment: @bessanalbessani use `var arr = inputVal.value.split(" ");`

Comment: i have modified the code so that ar inputVal = document.getElementById( "inputVal" ).value; and then use it but it still doesn't work and i don't know where the problem was !!!

Comment: @bessanalbessani then user browser's developer tool to check if there any error in log or debug code

Comment: mmmm i try the code on other browser(Firefox)but also it doesn't work !

Comment: i find that the function doesn't save the items after split in the array but i don't know why? !

Comment: @bessanalbessani what values should be saved?